# i want to render Image value in my Contact form 7 Dropdown I am using Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am building a Website on Wordpress. Where I have page which has 50 company logos and below logo section there is a form which is build by using Contact Form 7. The logo section is build by using HTML & CSS. In the Form I have a dropdown menu which has list of the name of the companies that I have added as logo. My requirement is that when a user clicks on any company logo. The name of the company should automatically get selected in the dropdown menu. Any suggestion or code will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have this structure for select dropdown in contact form 7

```
<div class="id_100">
  <select>
    <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now you have logo listing as below

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="01.jpg"><img src="01_th.jpg" title="val1" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="02.jpg"><img src="02_th.jpg" title="val2" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="03.jpg"><img src="03_th.jpg" title="val3" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

So you need to write jQuery on click on logo to get title and make a selection in select dropdown using the title as option value

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var img_title = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
        alert(img_title);
        jQuery("div.id_100 select").val(img_title);
    });
});
```